# vue3: why does $emit not work after promise fetch but only before

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

[image]
I am trying to pass the result of promise fetch from a child to parent component with emit. Emit works perfectly fine before the $fetch where my parent component was able to receive it, however the emit does not work in the image as seen where it is used after $fetch.

I have been trying to solve it for hours but have zero idea on why does it not work. Am learning, so do enlighten me if anyone knows the reason for it.

Thank you very much, appreciative of your help and time.

Cheers.

I tried to emit after fetch to API and expected my parent component to receive the event but it did not.

Comment: Please don't post code images. Instead post a code

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the fetch() hook that comes with Nuxt?  If so, it should be called outside your methods block and without the '$'.  Review the [Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching) on data fetching. You may also want to consider using the 'asyncData' hook depending on your use case.

Also, should it be a DELETE method instead? I don't know your API, but I assume a function called "remove" should perform a delete operation and not PUT.